# getty@tty1.serivce.service is permanently restarting Debian 11 live iso

Tags: debian, systemd, iso

I am trying to build my own Debian 11 live iso and struggling by getting a working getty console output. So far I have figured out that systemd is creating a wrong symlink when enabling the tty1 by using:

`systemctl enable getty@tty1.service`

It produces the following:

`Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service.service → /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`

However after enabling the service once again the correct symlink is created, so the faulty one can be removed.

But unfortunately when starting the live iso the getty@tty1.serivce.service is permanently restarting and I cannot figure out why. Subsequently I have only a blinking cursor and a black screen. If I follow the workaround and adjust the values within /etc/systemd/system.conf as described here: https://serverfault.com/a/845473 The screen is permanently flickering the status is as follows:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/getty@tty1.service.d
             └─live-config_autologin.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-09-16 17:49:05 UTC; 57ms ago
       Docs: man:agetty(8)
             man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
             http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
   Main PID: 119272 ((agetty))
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38480)
     Memory: 160.0K
        CPU: 9ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-getty.slice/getty@tty1.service
             └─119272 /bin/login -f user

Sep 16 17:49:05 live systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep 16 17:49:05 live login[119272]: pam_unix(login:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(user))
Sep 16 17:49:05 live login[119272]: Authentication failure
Sep 16 17:49:05 live systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Succeeded.
```

I have no idea why this behaves that buggy. Can anyone give me a hint? Basically I follow this tutorial for building the live iso: https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/

The GUI mode is working fine but I do not need this in this case.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Small update. I figured out that within the flickering tty1 console he tries to perform a auto login with the non-existent user "user". So I created the user and now it is logging into this user and the flickering stops. But this is not intended to be so. I only need the root user with non auto-login. I cannot find anything within the default /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service which enable the auto-login feature (?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after further investigating this and got a shot on the flickering text on the screen I figured out which was the issue: The live system automatically generates the live-user "user" which was not existent in my build. So with the post, here: https://serverfault.com/a/1030050 I managed to disable the creation of this user and now everything is working as expected.